# Shimano SPD-SL pedal tension adjustment not clicking, possible counterfeit?

Tags: shimano, pedals

So when I read the manual, it says the 105 pedal I have (5800) will have a click when tightening or loosening the tension adjuster, supposedly 4 clicks for 360 degree rotation, however mine don't click and just twist.

Now, I had someone I know just got scammed buying a fake Ultegra pedal and that got me into researching if the 105 has fakes, which... surprisingly does.

He said (I have not confirmed if this is true) that one of the signs of fakes are the tension adjuster not clicking when you turn it. I've had a R540 pedal in the past that clicks, but later bought another that doesn't click, and so I never had any suspicion when buying a 105 which also don't click. I thought maybe they changed it in later releases?

So if you have a 105 5800 can you confirm that it clicks or not? or do you have any Shimano pedal that you know is genuine but doesn't click when turning the tension adjuster? that would be great, thank you.

Edit: Additional info, mine weigh 135.3 for each pedal, which is 270.6 for both.

Edit 2: So I asked a friend who had the same pedal and his have clicks, so the answer is very likely that mine is fake. Unless someone else chime in who had the genuine had one with no click like mine.

Comment: Fake or not fake could depend on your location and the place where you bought the product. Also, the clicks tend to be very light, almost inaudible and can just be felt as a slight resistance while turning the adjustment screw. Don't expect loud clicks.

Comment: Yeah, I live in Indonesia and there is not exactly an "official" store for Shimano stuff. But we do have a few online stores where actual stores (verified) are selling there too instead of having their own websites. The thing was, I remember buying the first R540 pedal on a well known seller (which does have a click so I know how it feels), but not the second R540 and the 105 (which turns smoothly), since I didn't know that fakes are a thing. The 105 works no problem though, I'm just curious.

Comment: I have a pair of genuine R450 which clearly, audibly click, almost a 'snip' sound, very crisp. But you know they can do that, not a revelation.

Comment: Other than the missing click, do your pedals function correctly ?

Comment: A bit of backstory, the guy who discovered he just got a counterfeit got a problem where the cleat did not want to snap in place, because the very tip of the plastic claw that clamps the cleat got "bent" slightly downward preventing it from clipping in (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xmR9lKJhGXA). The thing is, it also happened to mine although not so bad, I thought it was normal for new pedals. I ended up clipping and unclipping in both direction to "set the plastic in" until it works fine. Bearing is also very smooth (its been months since I got it and it was rained on too).

Comment: However, one thing I noticed is, because of this claw issue, initially it does not clip in audibly loud as the older 105 I have tried before. But it gets better once the claw wear out a bit.
Other than that, I wouldn't have known if it was counterfeit, if it really is.

Comment: I think I got also counterfeit Shimano SPD-SL pedales (PD-R7000), that I bought second hand.
They were brand new. After installing them, I found it weird that they don't clip/unclip easily, even on the lowest adjustment setting.
When adjusting the tension spring, there's no click sound. Same as you mentioned.
It was driving me nuts until I saw your post. Thank you for pointing out the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The "click" you are referring to is inherent to the design of Shimano's SPD, SPD-R and SPD-SL pedals. Each click signifies an increase in torque of the spring which tightens the retaining jaw.

Broadly speaking, there are *two general possibilities*. The first is that the tightening mechanism has worn out and the clicks are now overlapping with one another. The pedal in question however, is assumed to be genuine, but worn out.

The second is that you have acquired/purchased a counterfeit and hence, the poor attention to quality resulting in the lack of "steps" or clicks in the tightening mechanism.

Comment: it is a fake. there are many videos from Philippines/Malaysia/Indonesia about these fake  SPD-SL pedals.